# Reputable TabletPC vendors

Tags: tablet, .net-framework

I'm developing software for tablet pcs and so far I've used some lenovo's (x41), some toshiba's (portege m200) and some gateways (M275). Granted: the machines we've gotten have predominantly been refurbs, but they're failing 80-90% of the time.

Part of the reason that they're failing is users inevitably dropping them, so I'm looking at potentially some rugged tablet pcs.

The problem that I'm running into is that

1. Current tablet pcs are high spec (much higher than I'm looking for at least)
2. The rugged tablet manufacturer space seems to be filled with lots of small companies that I don't trust yet.

I'm looking for tablet PCs (keyboard or no) that can support:

- XP tpc (optional win 7)
- single core 1.5-2ghz
- 1gb ram
- wifi
- optional gsm
- optional gps
- very optional vehicle docking solutions

The budget I've got is tight (but slightly flexible -

So are there any reputable tablet pc vendors out there that can do this.

Comment: Just because you are a programmer, that doesn't make all your questions programming related...or even all of your technology questions.  This one is more appropriate to superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Asus t101MT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834220713&Tpk=t101mt). It isn't rugged but it is cheap and has solid state storage device.

Answer (score 1):

Panasonic Toughbooks are pretty reputable.

They have a new "[Toughbook C1](http://www.panasonic.com/business/toughbook/business-rugged-toughbook-C1-convertible-tablet-pc.asp#/C1)" tablet coming out soon, as well as health-care oriented tablets ([H1 Field](http://www.panasonic.com/business/toughbook/business-rugged-toughbook-C1-convertible-tablet-pc.asp#/H1-Field) and [H1 Health](http://www.panasonic.com/business/toughbook/business-rugged-toughbook-C1-convertible-tablet-pc.asp#/H1-Health)).

They're generally not cheap due to the "toughness". :)

Comment: +1: Considering the price and what the company is willing to spend on hardware at this point in the process, I might just have to go with something cheap (that isn't refurb). Much appreciated.